# Custom jquery plugin is not working in page

Tags: jquery, plugins

I have created new custom jquery plugin for set height for selector. when it has been used in page, it is showing error in console " setEqualHeight is not a function". Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in Advance.

my code.

```js
 (function ($) {
     $.fn.setEqualHeight = function (ele) {
        var maxHeight = 0;
        var maxElement = null;

        $(ele).css({ "height": "auto" })

        $(ele).each(function (i) {
            if (($(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css("padding-bottom")) +     parseInt($(this).css("padding-top"))) > maxHeight) {
                maxHeight = $(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css("padding-top")) + parseInt($(this).css("padding-bottom"));
                maxElement = this;
            }
        });     
        $(ele).each(function () {
            $(this).height(maxHeight - parseInt($(this).css("padding-top")) - parseInt($(this).css("padding-bottom")))
        })
    };
})(jQuery);



$("body").setEqualHeight($(".box-borderDiv"));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: place `$("body").setEqualHeight($(".box-borderDiv"));` in a document ready function

Comment: You'll notice it doesn't do this for the snippet.  This means you are either calling it before it's defined or it's defined in a different scope.  Putting in doc ready as suggested by previous comment without explanation would fix it being executed in the wrong order.